# How to place an AR object in the real world at the real longitude and latitude with swift using realitykit/ ar kit etc?

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, arkit, simd, realitykit

Sorry if the question is basic, I'm a total novice. But I can't seem to find anything accomplishing what I want. This is my current code, which is supposedly placing the text entity I am generating at a specific longitude and latitude in the world (43/-76). But despite the fact that I am in Asia, I can see the text even though it is to be placed only in North America. What is happening!

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        guard let location = locations.last else { return }
        let position = SIMD3<Float>(43.037682, 7, -76.135040)

        // Create a red sphere with a radius of 0.1 meters
        let textMesh = MeshResource.generateText("Hendricks Chapel", extrusionDepth: 1)
        let textMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .orange, isMetallic: false)
        let textModel = ModelEntity(mesh: textMesh, materials: [textMaterial])

        let modelAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: position)
        modelAnchor.addChild(textModel)
        arView.scene.addAnchor(modelAnchor)
    }
```

I think this position is not being placed in the real world. The 7 is just an altitude point.

Comment: ARKit coordinates are not longitude and latitudes. And the AR world is not a globe. What you can do is only show the object when the device is *near* the desired geographic location.

Comment: Ah. Okay, how would someone go about accomplishing that?